# Can I add a parameter to a form through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, parameters

I have an HTML form that adds parameters to an URL. I only want the extra parameter added if a certain option is selected in the same form. So let's say I want to add the parameter "addedParameter=1" to the URL if "Commercial" is selected, otherwise I don't want the parameter to appear at all (other wise I get no results for "House" and "Land") Please let me know what I can do.

```
<select id="pt" value="pt" name="pt" onChange="addParameter()">
<option value="" name="">Select</option>
<option value="1" name="1">House</option>
<option value="2" name="2">Commercial</option>
<option value="3" name="3">Land</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="add" name="" value="1">

function addParameter(){
if(pt.selectedIndex == 1)
document.getElementById("add").name = "addedParameter";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="add" name="addedParameter" value="1">

function addParameter(){
if(pt.selectedIndex != 1)
  input = document.getElementById("add")
  parent = input.parentNode
  parent.removeChild(input)
}
```

This will remove the input when the additionalParameter is not set, otherwise it won't get changed.

**Edit:** alternative solution:

```
function addParameter(){
    if(pt.selectedIndex == 1) {
        document.getElementById("add").name = "addedParameter";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("add").name = "";
    }
}
```

Also see the docs for [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Comment: thanks you. Thanks to the people below too even though I didn't try your methods :)

Comment: So you will have to add it back in when the select is changed? @Mike, I suggest you try David's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that, rather than adding/removing the element based on a condition you should, instead, make use of the `disabled` attribute (only non-`disabled` elements are considered 'successful' and, therefore only non-`disabled` elements will have their names/values submitted):

```
function addParameter () {
    var sel = document.getElementById('pt'),
        input = document.getElementById('add');
    input.disabled = sel.selectedIndex != 2;
}

document.getElementById('pt').onchange = addParameter;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BJNhF/).

Note, in the demo I've removed the `type="hidden"` attribute-value, in order to visibly demonstrate the effect, but that's not required for this approach to work. Also, the conditional `input` has the `disabled="disabled"` attribute set by default (so if the form is submitted prior to this `select` being affected by the user it'll *still* not be accidentally submitted).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it clearer by using jQuery. When html definitions are not enough, I prefer to create and delete the (input) nodes all by dynamic javascript. The two ways you are discussing (changing by select event or by adding a submit event handler) also works with that :

```
function addParameter() {   
    if ($('#pt').val() == "2")  $('<input/>', { id: 'id_optionalParam', name: 'optionalParam', value: '1234', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo('#TheForm');
    else                        $('#id_optionalParam').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra parameter by adding an extra fidden field fo the form when needed option is selected, and remove it otherwise:

```
 function addParameter(){
   var addedParameterField = document.getElementById("addedParameter");
   if (pt.selectedIndex != 1) {
     if (addedParameterField) {
       addedParameterField.parentNode.removeChild(addedParameterField);
     }
   } else {
     if (!addedParameterField) {
       var addedParameterField = document.createElement("input");
       addedParameterField.type = "hidden";
       addedParameterField.name = "addedParameter"; 
       addedParameterField.value = "1";
       container = document.getElementById('myform');
       container.appendChild(addedParameterField);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Better than accepted answer, but still unnecessary dom manipulation

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach in this situation is to attach an event handler to the *submit* event of the form. Do what you need and then submit the form. Adding the input in the html and removing it after that is not so flexible.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        var form = document.getElementById("theform"),
            select = document.getElementById("pt");

        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if(select.value == 2) {
                var element = document.createElement("INPUT");
                element.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                element.setAttribute("name", "addedParameter");
                element.setAttribute("value", "1");
                form.appendChild(element);
            }
            form.submit();
        });

    }
</script>
<form method="get" id="theform">
    <select id="pt" value="pt" name="pt" onChange="addParameter()">
        <option value="" name="">Select</option>
        <option value="1" name="1">House</option>
        <option value="2" name="2">Commercial</option>
        <option value="3" name="3">Land</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: And what if user have one more submit handler, that uses ajax? If the form would be submitted more than once, added element will remain on it forever, regardless of what option is selected.

Comment: If that's the case then I'll suggest to use a jQuery, because there you can add as many handlers as you want. I don't know what exactly is the real use case, but the form should be submitted no matter what option is selected. That's whay I did in my example. It depends of the current context. But relaying on an event of some element inside the form is not a good idea. You may remove that element or add another select. Then the logic will be much complex.